# Does it make sense if there are two different classes that conform to the CBCentralManagerDelegate or CBPeripheralManagerDelegate protocol in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am implementing different service UUIDs, one for connection to other BLE devices and another one to implement a different use case, using some features from the iBeacon protocol. In the end, I have two different classes that are implementing the Central and Peripheral Manager, and they both conform to the corresponding delegates. Are both classes going to receive the corresponding events from each Central/Peripheral Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in general, it is possible and allowed to have two different instances of CLPeripheralManager and CLCentralManager and their corresponding delegates.  You will get callbacks on each one.

However, this may add unnecessary complications to your app in dealing with lifecycle events that are common to both instances (e.g. bluetooth power on/off).  Be careful to take this into account when you design your classes.

Typically, I build my apps that need both central and peripheral capabilities to have a single class for managing a CBPeripheralManager and callbacks, and a different single class for managing a CBCentralManager and callbacks.  But I always avoid having multiple instances of CBPeripheralManager or multiple instances of CBCentralManager, so there is only one delegate for the peripheral and one delegate for the central.

Comment: Thank you. That goes right at the heart of my question. Will follow your suggestion, it's a very sound architecture that way